# Batch | How to create several folders at same time

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a folders (2021; if it doesn't exist) at the same time in sub directories of Users with a batch.

```
if not exist "C:\Users\abc\2021" ( mkdir C:\Users\abc\2021)
if not exist "C:\Users\def\2021" ( mkdir C:\Users\def\2021)
if not exist "C:\Users\uvw\2021" ( mkdir C:\Users\uvw\2021)
if not exist "C:\Users\xyz\2021" ( mkdir C:\Users\xyz\2021)
```

But I want to simplify it and tried the following:

```
if not exist "C:\Users\*\2021"  ( mkdir C:\Users\*\2021)
```

That didn't work. Where is the mistake and how is it correct?

Comment: `for %%a in (abc def uvw xyz) do md "C:\users\%%a\2021" 2>nul` or `for /D %%a in (C:\users\*) do md "%%a\2021" 2>nul` depends on how to understand your question.

Comment: @Stephan, only a side note. as this is a one liner, good to make know that, in command line, `%a`  would suffice

Comment: correct, @elzooilogico, but as the question is tagged `batch-file`, I used batch file syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /d %%u in ("C:\users\*") do if not exist "%%u\2021\*" md "%%u\2021"
```

should do what you appear to want to do. See `for/?` from the prompt for details.

Comment: That looks good. In reality, I have spaces in the folder names, e.g.  "C:\users\1 my documents\*" I put it in quotes, but it always creates a folder called 1, which sucks. Normally it should work with quotes. Why doesn't that work in this case?

Comment: `if exist "item\."` also returns true for files, so you may want to use `if exist "item\*"`, which only evaluates to true for directories…

Comment: @ng-User, try by replacing `%%u` with `%%~u` (except for the very first occurrence, of course)…

Comment: @aschipfl: That worked, thanks!

Comment: @aschipfl : Yes, you're right about `*` against `.`. I don't understand the `%%~u` comment though. Worked for me as-corrected and with s new directoryname that contains spaces. `%%u` doesn't contain quotes, so I'm confused...

Comment: Your're right, @Magoo, `%%~u` shouldn't be necessary (unless there was no wildcard within `in ("C:\Users\name")`)…